showing white screen after running flutter app after stopping the project in android studio
I am having a problem in flutter in which when I run the app it runs as normally but when I stop the project and then run it again the white screen shows and I get this error in the run console;
I upgraded the Android Studio to the Jellyfish version then I started getting this problem, but even after downgrading to the Hedgehog version, the issue persists;
I tried solving it and what I found is that when you clear the cache or uninstall the app and then install the app again, it will work normally again, but if you stop the project again and run it, it will show a white screen again, so how can I solve it, I am unable to find any possible solution for the issue?
Console Output:
...
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:61880/gf6laqAzYm8=/ws
Syncing files to device sdk gphone x86 64...
I/le.timesheetapp( 5764): Compiler allocated 4533KB to compile void android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals()
[GETX] Instance "DropDownDataController" has been created
[GETX] Instance "DropDownDataController" has been initialized
[GETX] Instance "GetMaterialController" has been created
[GETX] Instance "GetMaterialController" has been initialized
E/emuglGLESv2_enc( 5764): device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glGetUniformLocation:2183 GL error 0x502
E/emuglGLESv2_enc( 5764): device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glGetUniformLocation:2183 GL error 0x502
E/emuglGLESv2_enc( 5764): device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glGetUniformLocation:2183 GL error 0x502
E/emuglGLESv2_enc( 5764): device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glGetUniformLocation:2183 GL error 0x502
E/emuglGLESv2_enc( 5764): device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glGetUniformLocation:2183 GL error 0x502
E/emuglGLESv2_enc( 5764): device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glGetUniformLocation:2183 GL error 0x502
E/emuglGLESv2_enc( 5764): device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glGetUniformLocation:2183 GL error 0x502
E/emuglGLESv2_enc( 5764): device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glGetUniformLocation:2183 GL error 0x502
E/emuglGLESv2_enc( 5764): device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glGetUniformLocation:2183 GL error 0x502
E/emuglGLESv2_enc( 5764): device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glGetUniformLocation:2183 GL error 0x502
E/emuglGLESv2_enc( 5764): device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glGetUniformLocation:2183 GL error 0x502
E/emuglGLESv2_enc( 5764): device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glGetUniformLocation:2183 GL error 0x502
E/emuglGLESv2_enc( 5764): device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glGetUniformLocation:2183 GL error 0x502 ...
'''


If u have added firebase then u did not set it up right OR if u have not done firebase then i would reocmmend u to create a new project and copy the code from the other one.
USE:
void main() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
    runApp(MyApp());
}


Oh ya i forgot that u also might have the java sdk set up for the emulator but u could use the chrome emulator

actually it is happening with all the projects, I guess it is emulator issue.
